# How many tilings by dominoes of this region?

Tags: dominoes

Here's a shape that could be tiled by dominoes.  Without the fault line there are 64 tilings.  With fault line how many possible tilings are there?

```
     _ _
   _|  _|_
 _|  _|   |_
|   |       |
|_ _|      _|
  |_     _|
    |_ _|
```

Comment: this is my first time posting a problem on here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the answer is

> 16

There are mendatory dominoes with the line :

> ```
>            _ _
>          _|_ _|_
>        _|_ _|   |_
>       |   |       |
>       |_ _|_     _|
>         |_ _|_ _|
>           |_ _|
> ```
>
> This leave 2 parts to tile. the left square has 2 possibilities, the right one is a little bite more complicated.
>
>  An easy way to do it to group the tiling by count of vertical dominoes among the 6 :
>
>  0 vertical -> 1 tiling
>
> ```
>    _ _
>  _|_ _|_
> |_ _|_ _|
> |_ _|_ _|
>   |_ _|
> ```
>
> 2 vertical-> 3 tilings (they always are in the middle column)
>
> ```
>    _ _       _ _       _ _
>  _|_ _|_   _|_ _|_   _|_ _|_
> | | |_ _| | |_ _| | |_ _| | | 
> |_|_|_ _| |_|_ _|_| |_ _|_|_|
>   |_ _|     |_ _|     |_ _|
> ```
>
> 4 vertical -> 3 tilings
>
> ```
>    _ _       _ _       _ _
>  _|_ _|_   _| | |_   _|_ _|_
> | | | | | | |_|_| | | |_ _| | 
> |_|_|_|_| |_|_ _|_| |_| | |_|
>   |_ _|     |_ _|     |_|_|
> ```
>
> 6 vertical -> 1 tiling
>
> ```
>    _ _ 
>  _| | |_ 
> | |_|_| |
> |_| | |_| 
>   |_|_|
> ```
>
> This gives 8 tilings for the right part.
>  The two part are independant so there is a total of 16 tilings for the cross.

Comment: i like how you drew each tiling

Answer (score 10):

I count:

> 16

reasoning:

> 4 tiles in the original are forced (a square w/ 3 edges has only 1 place to extend a domino into), leaving 2 mutually exclusive subgraphs.
>
> ```
>          _ _
>        _|_ _|_
>      _|_ _|a c|_
>     |   |e b d g|
>     |_ _|f     h|
>       |_ _|_ _|
>         |_ _|
> ```
>
> The left area clearly has 2 subgraphs.
>
> The right area: Based on placing on labeled squares ab, you force dominoes cd ef and gh. Filling in the remaining gives 2 unique tilings, which becomes 6 after you take into account reflections/rotations of the starting position. 2 more tilings are obtained by having the inital placement not present, which forces dominoes onto ac, ef, gh, and the bottom 2 squares which leaves another 2x2 square which has 2 tilings, giving a total of 6+2=8 graphs on the right section.
>
> mutually exclusive -> multiply the results ->2x8=16

Answer (score 4):

The top left part can be tiled in

> 2 ways; the top two dominoes are fixed and you have 2 options for the bottom 2x2 square.

Near the bottom, we have

> a single tile which is left-most; this determines the position of two horizontal dominoes.

We're left with

> a 12-tile shape in the form of a plus. If the top two tiles are covered by one horizontal domino, and the bottom two as well, there are **five** options for the remaining 4x2 rectangle (4 where the rectangle is split in half, 1 where it isn't). If the bottom one is done by two vertical dominoes, the rest is fixed, so that's **one** other option. If the top two tiles are covered by two vertical dominoes, we have **two** options depending on whether the bottom two tiles are covered by one or two dominoes. So that makes **eight** total.

Multiplying the independent shapes, we see that there are

> **16** total possibilities.